# Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds use the Requests

Tags: php, curl, httprequest

I can use the bellow curl for access the oauth token:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=test30&password=123456" -u"AD2fFTuUmce1jsnMHmCEPGkY3jDROjAAoNPkDyuc:Ve3AOBHsl7oFopZyWHZAwilEOIsblU8CPmU6v0wXMBRUn6UyoF1eM4YlCD94RMtietW0siIlLKarrowJmKUltBHBFt1xGhuCjQrTmpZeX40l7187E9U3V4xDBKtNAPcI" http://103.200.31.xx:8000/o/token/
```

the result is bellow:

```
{"token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 36000, "refresh_token": "0ULYiq5QpS3V5FjgGTygeoZZ5gO0Yf", "scope": "read write groups", "access_token": "SgFdP7rPBdoYoUG9hmjS3HvlcILFF6"}
```

but why I use the Requests for the token request, there will get error?

```
    $request = Requests::post('http://103.200.31.xx:8000/o/token', [
        // headers
    'Accept'=>'application/json'
 ], ['username'=>'test30', 'password'=>'123456'], [
        // options
        'auth' => new Requests_Auth_Basic(['AD2fFTuUmce1jsnMHmCEPGkY3jDROjAAoNPkDyuc', 'Ve3AOBHsl7oFopZyWHZAwilEOIsblU8CPmU6v0wXMBRUn6UyoF1eM4YlCD94RMtietW0siIlLKarrowJmKUltBHBFt1xGhuCjQrTmpZeX40l7187E9U3V4xDBKtNAPcI'])
    ]);

    return $request;
```

the error report:

```
Fri Jul 20 11:56:11.450296 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 5122:tid 139663067014912] [client 118.113.136.138:19584] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: [WHMCS Application] ERROR: Requests_Exception: cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds in /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/libs/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php:422 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/libs/Requests/library/Requests/Transport/cURL.php(177): Requests_Transport_cURL->process_response('', Array) #1 /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/libs/Requests/library/Requests.php(379): Requests_Transport_cURL->request('http://103.200....', Array, Array, Array) #2 /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/libs/Requests/library/Requests.php(268): Requests::request('http://103.200....', Array, Array, 'POST', Array) #3 /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/utils/utils.php(35): Requests::post('http://103.200....', Array, Array, Array) #4 /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qicloud_dedicate_servers.php(88): fetch_qicloud_access_tokens(Array) #5 {main} {"exception":"[object] (Requests_Exception(code: 0): cURL error 28: Connection timed out after ...\n', referer: http://www.example.net/qservers.php
```

---

**EDIT-01**

I set the timeout to 30, still this error, `after 10000 ms xxx`.

```
[
    // options
    'auth' => new Requests_Auth_Basic([QICLOUD_whmcs_pj_client_id, QICLOUD_whmcs_pj_client_secret]),
    'timeout' => 30,
]
```

where is the error?

---

**EDIT-02**

I set the `connect_timeout` to 30 too, but still get timeout error, says:

> Connection timed out after 30002 milliseconds

I don't think set timeout is the solution, because I use the `curl`, it request the token very quickly.

Comment: The 4th parameter to the `post()` function is an array of options. You can use this to set a timeout. The default is 10 seconds, which is confirmed by the error you're getting.  See the available options [HERE](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests/blob/master/library/Requests.php#L306)

Comment: @PatrickQ See my eidt-01

Comment: You may need to also set `connect_timeout`.  It depends on what's causing the request to take so long.

Comment: @PatrickQ see my eidt02, i set but still get the timeout error.

Comment: Well, it's waiting longer before triggering the error, so the changed did what it is supposed to.  I can't really speak to _why_ the connection is taking so long.  Is there a reason why you're not using the native [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) functions?

Comment: @PatrickQ Because I want to have a fail hander, and the request status code.